# I can't load the data which stored in my document directory

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9

When I am terminating the app then my data are successfully saved in document directory but when I start the app again the data is not visible.Here, its code of saving and loading of data.

```
func saveChecklistItems()
{
    let data = NSMutableData()

    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWithMutableData: data)

    archiver.encodeObject(items, forKey: "Checklists")

    archiver.finishEncoding()

    data.writeToFile(dataFilePath(), atomically: true)
}

func loadChecklistItems()
{
    let path = dataFilePath()

    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path)
    {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
        {
            let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData:data)

            if let checklistItems =  unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("ChecklistsItems") as? [ChecklistItem]
            {
                items = checklistItems
            }
            else
            {
                unarchiver.finishDecoding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have used the kay as

```
 archiver.encodeObject(items, forKey: "Checklists")
```

here you have used as ...

```
unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("ChecklistsItems") as? [ChecklistItem]
```

change it to ....

```
unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("Checklists") as? [ChecklistItem]
```

Comment: thanks @sriram hegde. It works and definitely I will vote you.

Comment: I meant below the voting system there is a tick mark to say this answer works , if you click on that , that would help a lot!